# How to execute commands read from the txt file using shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I tried to execute commands read it from txt file. But only 1st command is executing, after that script is terminated. My script file name is shellEx.sh is follows:

```
echo "pwd" > temp.txt
echo "ls" >> temp.txt
exec < temp.txt
while read line
do
exec $line
done
echo "printed"
```

if I keep echo in the place of exec, just it prints both pwd and ls. But i want to execute pwd and ls one by one.

o/p am getting is:

```
$ bash shellEx.sh
/c/Users/Aditya Gudipati/Desktop
```

But after pwd, ls also need to execute for me.
Anyone can please give better solution for this?

Comment: Is "/c/Users/Aditya Gudipati/Desktop" a  single path and do you experience problems with white space, or is it two tokens?

Comment: Why are you reading the file line by line, instead of just sourcing the file with `. temp.txt`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A file with one valid command per line is itself a shell script. Just use the `.` command to execute it in the current shell.

```
$ echo "pwd" > temp.txt
$ echo "ls" >> temp.txt
$ . temp.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its working fine for my scenario

Answer (score 2):

`exec` in bash is meant in the [Unix sense](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)) where it means "stop running this program and start running another instead". This is why your script exits.

If you want to execute line as a shell command, you can use:

```
line="find . | wc -l"
eval "$line"
```

(`$line` by itself will not allow using pipes, quotes, expansions or other shell syntax)

To execute the entire file including multiline commands, use one of:

```
source ./myfile # keep variables, allow exiting script
bash myfile     # discard variables, limit exit to myfile
```